# How to check if excel file being imported has no records in access vba?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to import an excel file into a table in Access. But, if there are no records or data in the Excel file, I want to generate an error message popup. 
How do I check if the excel file is empty in VBA?

Comment: Which version of Access? Have you tried finding the number of records in the resulting table?

Comment: Access 2010. I was trying something like this If DCount("*", tbl_ClientDataUpload) = 0 Then
ErrorMsg:
    message = MsgBox("Data missing from input file", vbExclamation)
End If

Comment: I think I figured it out, my syntax was wrong, so it was not reading my table. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it. Please add your own answer and mark it as correct so that others can benefit in the future & welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
If DCount("*", "tbl_Name") = 0 Then 
ErrorMsg: message = MsgBox("Data missing from input file", vbExclamation) 
End If
```